# Maximum size that can be allocated

Tags: linux, memory

Can I allocate more memory than `VmallocTotal` given in `/proc/meminfo` ?

Answer (score 1):

`vmalloc()` is an internal kernel function.  It is not available to user programs.  It has no effect on allocations of memory for user programs.  `VmallocTotal` limits the allocations of kernel code which calls `vmalloc()` (and `VmallocTotal` does not change, either automatically or manually).

Maximum size of memory that can be "allocated" by user programs depends on overcommit settings.  I write "allocated" in scare quotes, because "overcommit" somewhat contradicts the idea of "allocating memory".  One explanation is here, you can search on the keywords it uses for other explanations: https://serverfault.com/questions/606185/how-does-vm-overcommit-memory-work

As the [kernel doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting) puts it, system calls like `mmap()` or the old `sbrk()` do not allocate memory by default.  They return "address space".  Real memory will be mapped on-demand if/when it is written to.  Memory is mapped in terms of pages (usually 4096 bytes).